# ADB and 6.0 compatibility

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

so what should I update exactly to get adb working with my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0)
the device always appears offline when I check `adb devices` since I updated from lollipop
I've searched and all what I found was for windows, feeling kinda lost here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info

Comment: thank you so much, I was searching for USB Drivers that's why I couldn't get anywhere :)